# Is it bad practice for scripts to write over parts of themslves?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a script (a Rails runner, if it matters) that will run periodically. It uses a gem to query a SQL database. Because that database does not update existing rows, but merely adds new ones to reflect changes to data, the script will run a query that only finds objects with an id greater than the id that was in the database the last time the script was run.

In what file should that id be stored? Is it bad practice to store it in the script and have the script write over itself, and if so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the ID in a separate file. Not only would the script writing over itself be more difficult to do correctly, but that practice would also be likely to confuse users, and could result in a whole host of other problems, such as additional friction when trying to version control the script or update it to a new version.

Under most circumstances, data and code should be separate.

Comment: ...during my work with Docker I've learned to separate persistent data from the app's code, so that in case I have to upgrade the codebase, that information is not lost, it's retrieved from persistent storage (mounted Docker volume) after upgrade is done.